# Gradle sync failed: Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to test my ionic app in android studio. It is throwing the below error.

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified.
```

Any solution for this ? What am I doing wrong.

Here is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.1.0'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:+'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
}
```

Comment: Please give compile sdk version.Like in app level gradle.

Comment: please share your gradle file code

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pt.planner"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 24
        versionName "2.4.0"
        multiDexEnabled true`

Comment: compilesdkversion should be same as targetsdkversion

Comment: @Yogesh Borhade - Please check, I have shared the file details

Comment: "use this code in your gradle file or check below code "       






android {
 //   compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sportden.proquize"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

Comment: @YogeshBorhade - Could you please confirm to which gradle file I should I add this code. I can see multiple gradle files. 
1. build.gradle - under android folder
2. build.gradle - under app folder
3. build.gradle - under cordovaLib folder

Comment: 1 st way )instead of Project select android and then find 
GradleScript -> build.gradle -> (module:app)
2 nd way ) app(folder )-> builde.gradle

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are using **android support** library of `27.+` so you will have to give `sdk` version `27` as `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` otherwise your project does not know for which platform your project should be built. These parameter should be given in android directory like this in **build.gradle(app)**:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abc.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Just paste this code below `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` this line

Comment: Thanks Ghulam Moinul Quadir, it works now. But still the build fails and gives an error 
1. cannot find symbol class CallbackContext
2. cannot find symbol class CordovaPlugin
3. cannot find symbol class PluginResult
4. cannot find symbol class CordovaPlugin
Please help

Comment: @AmitAnand share you `build.gradle(ProjectName)`

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I resolved the issue by replacing the old plugin applying syntax:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

with the new plugins DSL in all my `build.gradle` files:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case , I fixed it by setting the Android gradle plugin version and gradle version to the latest. [image]

Answer (score 4):

If you are working on a old project and using latest version of Android studio then simply change

```
compileSdk 27
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

on your app level build.gradle file. it will fix this error

Answer (score 4):

**compileSdkVersion is depricated**

from SDK 33 and above **don't use**

```
compileSdkVersion 33
```

**but use:**

```
 android {
   // compileSdkVersion 33 and above
    defaultConfig {
        compileSdk 33
    }
...}
```

Answer (score 3):

if someone encounter this problem after upgrading **android studio to (Flamingo AGP 8)**, they updated `compileSdkVersion` field to be `compileSdk` so you have to update this line in your gradle.build to be like this:

```
compileSdkVersion 33
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, with Capacitor and the error "*compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle*", I had to edit the file `android/app/build.gradle` by adding `compileSdk 33` in `defaultConfig`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            […]
        }
        release {
            […]
        }
    }
    compileSdk compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "[…]"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 33
        compileSdk 33
        versionCode 33
        versionName '33'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            […]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was coming from my own plugin and I fixed it by adding the following line to my plugin.xml file: (which I found simpler than updating the plugin's gradle file)

```
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="30" />
         ...
```

Comment: It stopped working again. Don't know why cordova is being bit intermittent for me.

Comment: cordova platform add android was throwing error but build was still running. Updating the plugin's gradle file to `dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0"
}` filed my issue

Answer (score 1):

in file variables.gradle change compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion this file found in android/variables.gradle

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 22
    compileSdkVersion = 32
    targetSdkVersion = 32
    androidxActivityVersion = '1.4.0'
    androidxAppCompatVersion = '1.4.2'
    androidxCoordinatorLayoutVersion = '1.2.0'
    androidxCoreVersion = '1.8.0'
    androidxFragmentVersion = '1.4.1'
    coreSplashScreenVersion = '1.0.0-rc01'
    androidxWebkitVersion = '1.4.0'
    junitVersion = '4.13.2'
    androidxJunitVersion = '1.1.3'
    androidxEspressoCoreVersion = '3.4.0'
    cordovaAndroidVersion = '10.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please Add Below Line in your gradle file**

```
  compileSdkVersion 26
```

**please check below code for reference**

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId ""
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: There was an error in my app/build.gradle, hence it was not
>   reading compileSDKVersion property. When I commented such a line, the
>   error went away:

```
//def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);
```

Firstly I got to follow this link:

[ReactNative: Building from source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/wiki/Building-from-source)

Then this:

[ReactNative: android-development-environment](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment)

Then you can have this added in your settings.gradle file:

```
//
include ':ReactAndroid'
//
project(':ReactAndroid').projectDir = new File(
    rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid')
```

---

For my ReactViro Sample project I also had to add dependencies from react-native node_modules directory:

```
    implementation project(':arcore_client') // remove this if AR not required
    implementation project(':gvr_common')
    implementation project(path: ':viro_renderer')
    implementation project(path: ':react_viro')
```

and

in my settings.gradle:

```
//
include ':react_viro', ':arcore_client', ':gvr_common', ':viro_renderer'
project(':arcore_client').projectDir = new File('../node_modules/react-viro/android/arcore_client')
project(':gvr_common').projectDir = new File('../node_modules/react-viro/android/gvr_common')
project(':viro_renderer').projectDir = new File('../node_modules/react-viro/android/viro_renderer')
project(':react_viro').projectDir = new File('../node_modules/react-viro/android/react_viro')
//
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating required Package.json libraries worked for me try it out. Most of the error will get resolved.

Remove `Jcenter()` from `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

**Add this below mention code to your android/build.gradle**

1. First, Save your code and uninstall your Android Studio and install again.
2. Add this line in your android/build.gradle .

   def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

   ```
    allprojects {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                // Remove this override in 0.66, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
                force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
            }
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify android.buildToolsVersion from Build Tools For `buildToolsVersion` in version `27.0.3` or higher there's no need to specify `buildToolsVersion`.

> Build Tools 27.0.3 or higher. Keep in mind, you no longer need to
> specify a version for the build tools using the
> android.buildToolsVersion property—the plugin uses the minimum
> required version by default.

Source ([developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/past-releases/past-agp-releases/agp-3-1-0-release-notes))