# Gradle sync error after android update (compileSdkVersion is not specified)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx

I had a project. Its work so well before updater version 3.2.1. When try sync gradle project, i got some error, but i can fix that. But i had one issue and cant find a way. 
Here my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 7x
    versionName "1.0.7x"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
implementation('com.omertron:themoviedbapi:4.2') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'junit'
}
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation files('libs/okhttp-3.8.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/okio-1.13.0.jar')
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
//noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
implementation 'javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.3@aar'
implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.1.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation files('libs/xxx.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
     all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven{
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
}

//task clean(type: Delete) {
//    delete rootProject.buildDir
//}
```

Anw, I find this: 
[Gradle sync failed: Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530889/gradle-sync-failed-cause-compilesdkversion-is-not-specified)

But, its not help anymore. So, anyone can help me ?

Comment: why do you have `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` inside `allprojects {}`?

Comment: I think its point we looking for. after when i comment this line. Rebuild work well

Comment: Good to hear that you finally get it work.

Comment: Yea. Anw, thanks you so much, when spend too much time help me, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change `targetSdkVersion` to 28 and change all your `compile` to `implementation`
2. make sure that your top level `build.gradle` has the proper `google()` repo configured. E.g.

   ```
   repositories {
       google() // be the first one. 
       jcenter()
   }
   ```

My related answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839

Comment: hell. i forgot that. but, after i change. Its still error. Any ideal ?

Comment: can update your question with your updated `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` ?

Comment: hmm, cannot be ... or move this one `maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }` to be the first in both two places of **repositories**