# compileSdkVersion erro getting in android

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Below is my adnroid , build.gradle file getting error
"com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle"
While its is there , do I need to add anyother place .
Please suggest

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version= '1.6.20'
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1')
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        //classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
         //classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1') // or recent
         classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle sync failed: Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530889/gradle-sync-failed-cause-compilesdkversion-is-not-specified)

Answer (score 1):

make compile sdk version and targetSdkVersion same, it will be better if you make the both version 31;