# > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

when I wanted to run on the emulator, I experienced this error. even though I didn't change the code at all

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/dika/Mobile/app/android/build.gradle' line: 27
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
> > Cannot invoke method substring() on null object

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 756ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

and this is my `android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this `android/app/build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) 
      

android {
    namespace "com.satwaliar.satwa_liar"
    compileSdkVersion 30
    
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.satwaliar.satwa_liar"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('/Users/handikadjatidharma/satwa_liar.jks')
            storePassword '123456'
            keyAlias = 'satwa_liar'
            keyPassword '123456'
        }
    }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
}
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

CHeck the version of build graddle and build tool.
And set the best version of compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion for this. otherwise your project does not know for which platform your project should be built.

This is the best answer.
[Gradle sync failed: Cause: compileSdkVersion is not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530889/gradle-sync-failed-cause-compilesdkversion-is-not-specified)