how do i solve gradle and version deprecatory issues?
I need help with getting the right compatible versions for each dependency so their are no conflicts when trying to run android, I'd like to keep versions as latest as possible for json.file
{
  "name": "clone",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.4.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.0",
    "react-native-encrypted-storage": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.17.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

what do I need to change for the gradle files?
I'm getting this error, detailed help appreciated:
BUILD FAILED in 5s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build completed with 
2 failures. 1: Task failed with an exception. ----------- * Where: Build file 'C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\Personal Instagram Clone\Frontend\instagramClone\android\app\build.gradle' 
line: 84 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Could not read script 'C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\Personal Instagram Clone\Frontend\instagramClone\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle' 
as it does not exist. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. 
> Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. 
============================================================================== 2: Task failed with an exception. ----------- * 
What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. 
Please add it to build.gradle * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. 
> Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more 
help at https://help.gradle.org. ============================================================================== BUILD FAILED in 5s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.


As the error suggests can you check compileSdkVersion. Read this answer for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/77227590/24823442


This error is likely caused by a missing or incorrectly linked react-native module.
Delete the node_modules directory and the package-lock.json file in your project's root directory.
Run npm install to reinstall your project's dependencies.


I did this multiple times, even tried yarn. I should note the repo is two years old
